# ArcMap runs custom script once and then it crashes on second run

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, sql-server

So I made a script that takes data from an MSSQL database and inserts it into a featureclass. I added the script to a toolbox and am able to run the tool from within ArcMap 10.1.  The problem is that I cannot re-run the tool.  When I try and run it a second time, ArcMap crashes.  I'll start ArcMap again, run the tool and when I try and run it the second time ArcMap crashes again.

By calling `arcpy.AddMessage()` coupled with `time.sleep(5)` I have narrowed the problem down to one line of code:
`pyodbc_cursor.execute("{call dbo.GetData(?)}",(DataID))`

It seems like even though I `close()` and `del` all my pyodbc variables (connection, cursor, row) after I'm done with them the cursor is causing a problem when the script is executed the second time around.

This seems like some kind of bug between ArcMap, arcpy and pyodbc

Comment: Ok so unchecking the _'Run Python script in process'_ seems to fix this issue and I can run the script more than once without ArcMap crashing.  I don't think this is a good answer since it doesn't really answer why ArcMap would crash on the second execution of a pyodbc cursor that was closed and deleted.

Comment: Experienced the same with a generic python script. Where it was using the logging module and importing a logger, on the first run everything was OK. On second run the logger was NoneType Obect and crashed the script. Can confirm that `ToolBox > right click script > Source > (Untick) Run Python script in Process` solved the problem in ArcMap 10.6.1